# PHP: Check duplicate array key in objects array.

Tags: php, arrays

I have an objects array as following

> ```
>  [{"ChannelName":"39-40","Text":"haha"},
>   {"ChannelName":"39-40","Text":"lala"}
>   {"ChannelName":"40-41","Text":"bla bla"},
>   {"ChannelName":"40-41","Text":"kha kha"}]
> ```

How can I check duplicate value in ChannelName. What I need to do is when ChannelName exists in array object, I want to replace the ChannelName with new Text. How php check duplicate ChannelName and how to replace of old Text attribute with new Text attribute if ChannelName duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicates in array of objects on the basis of specific keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913229/find-duplicates-in-array-of-objects-on-the-basis-of-specific-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution.

```
$json = <<<JSON
[{"ChannelName":"39-40","Text":"haha"},
{"ChannelName":"39-40","Text":"lala"},
{"ChannelName":"40-41","Text":"bla bla"},
{"ChannelName":"40-41","Text":"kha kha"}]
JSON;

$json_array = json_decode( $json, TRUE );

$new_array = array();
$exists_array    = array();
foreach( $json_array as $element ) {
    if( !in_array( $element['ChannelName'], $exists_array )) {
        $exists_array[]    = $element['ChannelName'];
    }
    else{
        $element['ChannelName'] = 'New Value';
    }
    $new_array[] = $element;
}

print json_encode( $new_array );
```

Here at New Value section you can change your value as per your requirement.